# LinearLayout does not set the required layout_height attribute

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-linearlayout

I'm making a layout and applying some styles. so:

```
<style name="LayoutSmallMap">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">180dip</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_corner</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">5dip</item>
        <item name="android:padding">3dip</item>
</style>
```

And I use this:

```
<LinearLayout 
       style="@style/LayoutSmallMap">

</LinearLayout>
```

But when I test the phone before it gives error and now states:

**LinearLayout does not set the required layout_height attribute**

He is not finding the attribute in my style?

**Do not know if it's the best solution, but it worked for me:**
Target SDK: 2.3 and
**minSdkVersion="7"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use android:layout_width and android:layout_height in styles.
Modify your code as follows.

```
<style name="LayoutSmallMap">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_corner</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">5dip</item>
        <item name="android:padding">3dip</item>
</style>


<LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="180dip"  
       style="@style/LayoutSmallMap">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I had already done so, this solves my problem, but I wanted it to be everything in style, so the source code of the layout would be more beautiful to visualize. Thanks

Comment: @AderbalNunes how to accept this answer we want only with no height in this layout `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`and `android:layout_width="180dip"` it is possible..

Comment: is required for LinearLayout, can not only use the style.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<style name="LayoutSmallMap">         
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_corner</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dip</item>
    <item name="android:padding">3dip</item>
</style>
```

layout

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="180dib"
    style="@style/LayoutSmallMap">

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and `android:layout_width="180dip"`